# Wrap text with ... for percentage width for div

Tags: html, css

I want to wrap text from ... when it's too long.

The requirements are:

- box is between 40% - 70% of the parent's width
- the text is 90% of the width of this box
- the text is centered

I have pre-made code but it doesn't work properly.

Should:

- The first thing you should do is to expand the box to its maximum size, and then when it cannot expand, it will fold

Currently adding ... before it reaches its maximum width (you can change the length of the text and check it

Below I present how it works:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.inner {
  max-width: 70%;
  min-width: 40%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FFFDD0;
}

.center {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.text {
    color: #000000;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner center">
    <span class="text">Content a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`inline` boxe cannot receive any size, `display` needs to be reset to any other value that meets your requirement.

40% - 70% can be set via `min-width` and `max-width`.

From what i basicly understood, you'd be trying to do something alike :

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid;
}

.inner {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 70%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FFFDD0;
  border: solid;
  margin: auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;/* inline cannot be sized, a resize is necessary*/
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 90%;/* works if not an inline display box*/
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner center">
    <span class="text">Content a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner center">
    <span class="text">Content a b c d e f g h i k l m</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner center">
    <span class="text">Content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**but also** : *when it cannot expand, it will fold* confuses me while you use `white-space:nowrap` and ellipsis. It won't *fold* in some ways  but will truncate the text and show dots .